# Expression.Call() overload for calling an instance method expecting a single argument is missing. Is there a reason for this?

Tags: c#, c#-5.0, linq-expressions

Looking at the documented overloads available for the `Expression.Call(),` method, I can find the following overloads to obtain an expression node that will perform a call to an instance method expecting:

1. no arguments
2. two arguments
3. three arguments
4. four arguments
5. variable arguments via an `Expression` array
6. variable arguments via an `IEnumerable<Expression>`

**What would be the rationale for not having an overload expecting a single argument?**

In my mind, the method signature for the single argument case would be:

```
public static MethodCallExpression Call(
    Expression instance,
    MethodInfo method,
    Expression arg0);
```

I don't see any other overloads that would collide with this method signature, so I really don't get why the method is missing. 
I understand that the overloads expecting an array or an `IEnumerable` would  allow me to create an `Expression` for the single-argument case, but that would also apply to the other available overloads so I am curious if there is something I don't see that would explain why this overload is missing.

Comment: as i see in source code there is overload with `params Expression[] arguments`. that should give you  the ability to pass single argument.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary yes, I noticed that. In fact that overload allows us to call a method with whatever number of arguments are required, that's why I find odd that they are offering non-array versions for frequent number of arguments except for a single argument.

Comment: [Overload list on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.call.aspx)

Comment: Interestingly, the static version has the internal `MethodCallExpression1` but the instance version does not have a corresponding `InstanceMethodCallExpresson1`, it just uses `InstanceMethodCallExpressionN`.

Comment: @NetMage Ha, good catch. It's a really interesting decision, if it was deliberate.

Comment: The .Net Core source has `InstanceMethodCallExpression1` and an `internal Expression.Call(e, m, e)` that has the comment `// COMPAT: This method is marked as non-public to ensure compile-time compatibility for Expression.Call(e, m, null).`.